# Motivation for the shape of the theta vacua

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, quantum-chromodynamics, topological-phase, instantons

I understand that the reason why we construct the theta vacua is because instantons allow tunnelling between different vacuum states, $\left|n\right>$. This means that we have to consider a real vacuum state
$$
\left|\Omega\right> = \sum_n a_n \left|n\right>.
$$
Now, my question is *why do we have $a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,e^{i\theta n}$*, so that
$$
\left|\theta\right> = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,\sum_n e^{i\theta n} \left|n\right>.
$$

I see that this allows some neat properties like orthogonality,
$$
 \left<\theta\right| \mathcal{O} \left|\theta'\right> = 0 \quad \text{if} \quad \theta \neq \theta',
$$
or it being an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian,
$$
 H \left|\theta\right> = \lambda \left|\theta\right>,
$$
but is the theta vacuum the only vacuum structure that allows this for QCD? Why is this the correct QCD vacuum (at least when there are no fermions)?